# Retrieve my social security number from a long time ago

Tags: social-security

I don't have or remember my social security number, which I got in 1979. I want to find my number, since I am in the country with no visa. What can I do?

Comment: Which country?  Which country are you a citizen of? Did you enter the country legally?

Comment: Are you hoping that having a social security number will somehow mitigate problems related to your immigration status?  It will not.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you start at [this website](https://www.americansabroad.org/obtaining-reclaiming-your-social-security-number-ssn/). You can learn about the process for recovering your SSN. You should also consider visiting your nearest SS office. I don't believe they ask to see a visa before rendering assistance.

Good luck.